# crear trigger en mysql para que los productos en stock bajo se escriban en una tabla de productos aparte

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure, trigger

Estoy intentanto hacer un trigger para que cuando en la tabla Producto el stock sea menor o igual que stock_limite los atributos de dicho producto se escriban en una tabla prostocklim (su utilidad es tener constancia de los productos en stock bajo de existencias).
La estructura de mi base de datos es la siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El stock se reduce cada vez que se produce una venta, a través de un trigger que actualiza  el stock con el numeroItems de la tabla detalleventa.
El codigo que he escrito es el siguiente:

```
DELIMITER $$                    
CREATE TRIGGER insertProEnStockLim AFTER UPDATE ON producto FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF(NEW.stock <= stock_limite) THEN 
    INSERT INTO prostocklim (fechaIngreso, idProducto, nombreProLim, stock, stockLimite) VALUES (NOW(), new.idProducto, new.nombre_pro, new.stock, new.stock_limite)
END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Y el error que obtengo me dice que no reconoce el campo stock_limite del condicional, supongo que debería crear un procedimiento y agregar parametros:

```
#1327 - Undeclared variable: stock_limite
```

Comment: Ponle un `new.` a `stock_limite` tal que así:  `new.stock_limite`.

Comment: Vale. Gracias por la ayuda. Agrego el codigo que me ha funcionado finalmente:

Answer (score 1):

El código que finalmente ha funcionado:

```
DELIMITER $$   
CREATE TRIGGER insertProEnStockLim AFTER UPDATE ON producto FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
   IF(new.stock <= new.stock_limite) THEN 
        INSERT INTO prostocklim (fechaIngreso, idProducto, nombreProLim, stock, stockLimite) VALUES (NOW(), new.idProducto, new.nombre_pro, new.stock, new.stock_limite); 
   END IF; 
END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Este script crea un disparador en mi base de datos que se activa tras producirse un UPDATE en la tabla producto. El disparador se ejecuta por cada fila que se actualiza, que recibe un UPDATE. Es disparador evalúa los valores actualizados de stock y stock_limite de la tabla producto, si el valor de stock es menor que stock_limite entonces se lleva a cabo un INSERT INTO la tabla prostocklim con los valores que se observan en el script.

Comment: No olvides explicar el funcionamiento de tu script en base a [answer]: puede que otros usuarios más adelante tengan un problema similar, y puede que no comprendan cómo funciona el script en tu respuesta. Luego, [acepta](/help/accepted-answer) la misma.